# Spring integration - spillter handling big lists

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-integration

In my proejct we have a 
-spring integration poller which gets bunch of records  for every five minutes 
- sends it to the splitter,  which splits the records using the taskexector in multi thread fashion (with pool size as 4)  at the output channel and send each record for further processing.

This all working fine. However the issue is with splitter blocking until it completely process the passed list.

Our requirement is if another list is passed to splitter then it needs to process it in parallel without waiting for the first list processing is completed. I tried to put another task executor to input channel of the spillter , but it did not resolve the issue.

How to get the splitter work is parellel for two given input lists to them , each inturn run multithreads for its individual passed lists.

Configuration:

using the spring integration 2.2.0.RELEASE and spring 3.1.1.RELEASE versions

```
<integration:channel id="splitterChannel"/>
    <integration:channel id="serviceRequestChannel"/>
    <integration:channel id="aggregatorChannel"/>

    <integration:channel id="routerChannel" >
        <integration:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
    </integration:channel>

    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="4"/>


   <integration:inbound-channel-adapter
            id="inboundAdapter"
            method="retrieveReadyRecords"
            channel="splitterChannel"
            ref="inboundChannelAdapter" auto-startup="true">
       <integration:poller
                trigger="batchtrigger"/>
    </integration:inbound-channel-adapter>


    <integration:splitter
            input-channel="splitterChannel"
            expression="payload"
            output-channel="routerChannel"/>


  <integration:recipient-list-router input-channel="routerChannel">
        <integration:recipient channel="aggregatorChannel"      selector-expression="!payload.state.equals('Y')"/>
        <integration:recipient channel="serviceRequestChannel"  selector-expression="payload.state.equals('N')"/>
    </integration:recipient-list-router>


--- also further configuration for below service requests sending to aggretor
```

Comment: Please show your config and splitter code (if it uses a custom `<bean/>`). There's no reason a stateless splitter should prevent multi-threaded messages from processing in parallel. Although there is an issue with `<groovy:script/>` components that is resolved in 3.0.

Comment: Hi update the configuraiton. can you please look and advice

Answer (score 0):

You put your `ExecutorChannel` AFTER the splitter. The poller won't be triggered again until the splitter sends its output to `routerChannel` which is where the handoff happens.

I suggest you remove the dispatcher from the `routerChannel` and add the `taskExecutor` to the poller instead.

That way, the poller does the handoff before the splitter and will be available for the next trigger.

You should also use the latest 2.2.x release (2.2.6).

Comment: Thankyou .The issue does not seems to be with the poller .With the existing configuration I see the poller is being executed and sending the next List of records to the splitter and after that it is waiting for the previous Listto complete the processing. let me try that configuration you suggested and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I tried with the configuration you mentioned . It worked fine however at the splitter level i would like the multi threading as well to make it fast. If I add the task executor at the spliiter router level as mentioned above I am running into the same issue even if I add the task executor at the poller level.  is there a configurtion by which we can  get the multi threading at the poller level and at the spillter lveve?

Comment: Do you mean `within` the splitter (for each message)? What I suggested will make each inbound message to the splitter run on its own thread.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. yes. i want each inbound message to the spillter run in separate thread  (which you suggested and worked fine) and also i want each message that is spillted by spliiter also run in its own thread (this worked fine with above configuration which i gave initially). when i combined the both configuration it is not working and waiting for the spillter to complete the intial List passed before the second List is being processed by the splitter (whcih looks like same  the initial issue i faced).

Comment: Ok; so you need to keep the task executor in the `routerChannel` channel too. That way each message generated by the splitter will run on its own thread. That said, with a pool size of only 4, your parallelism will be limited. You might want to use a different executor in each case.